# MySQL PHP won't fetch all rows

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

While trying to make an overview of added "friends", the following code only returns the last added friend.

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE bruger1='$usrname' AND status='Godkendt'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  $venner=$rows['bruger2'];
}
$tbl_name="brugere";
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE email LIKE '$venner%'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<div id="searchcenter">
  <div id="searchtop"></div>
<?php
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
  <a href="http://festbook.dk/profil/start.php?r=profil&id=<? echo $rows['id']; ?>" class="profilresult">
    <img src="<? echo $rows['profilbilled']; ?>">
    <p><b>Navn: </b><? echo $rows['navn']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Mail: </b><? echo $rows['email']; ?></p>
    <p><b>Hjem: </b><? echo $rows['adresse']; ?></p>
    <p><b>FacebookID: </b><? echo $rows['facebook']; ?></p>
  </a>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

What can I do to make it work correctly? Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried running the query manually and verified that you are, in fact, retrieving more than one row?

Comment: Is $bruger2 the email, as well as the field email? It's very confusing.

Comment: $bruger1 is the email of me in this example and $bruger2 is the email of the "friend" added

Comment: Please note that `mysql_*` is also a deprecated feature and will not work in the (possibly) near future.

Comment: Perhaps you'll get a better answer if you describe how your database tables look and then ask how to select friends of someone with id=.. or email=.. in the table .... You have at least one PHP problem here but the big issue is the SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by querying multiple tables...

```
$tbl_name="brugere";
$tbl_name2="venner";
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name, $tbl_name2 WHERE email=bruger2 AND status='Godkendt'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

Thanks for the help anyways! :D